# Is a machine Turing-complete when it can decide a context-sensitive language?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, formal-grammars, turing-completeness

If a machine can decide a context-sensitive language (like the language of palindromes with a non-linear center) is that fact a proof that the machine is Turing-complete?

Can this be used to prove Turing completeness of a programming language when a program that can decide a string of a context-sensitive language can be written in that programming language?

Or else, can the proof be achieved by using a recursively enumerable language such as the language of prime numbers?

Comment: The language of the first paragraph is a bit nonsensical. We usually do not refer to a single machine, or to a single program, as "Turing complete" (or "not Turing complete"). For that, we would need to consider a class of machines, or a class of programs (e.g., a programming language). The main question to answer here is: "given any computable function, is there a machine/program/device in my computation model that computes said function?". If so, the whole computation model (not just a single machine/...) is said to be Turing complete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  Context-sensitive languages [can be recognized by linear-time nondeterministic Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language), which are not Turing complete.

The ability to recognize a recursively enumerable set also does not prove that the programming language is Turing-complete.  For instance, the set $\{0,1\}^*$ is recursively enumerable, but is recognizable by a DFA, which is not Turing complete.

Or, consider a programming language with only two constructs: if-then-else statements, and "isprime?()", a primitive function that can be applied to any integer to test whether it is prime.  Such a programming language can recognize the language of prime numbers, but is not Turing-complete.